# Determining whether a Function is Even or Odd given a specific Domain

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, even-and-odd-functions

I have learned that,to determine if a function is even or odd, I should use the following Formula:
if f(-x)=f(x) ---> f(x) is Even.
if f(-x)=-f(x)---> f(x) is Odd.
if neither, well then neither.

But, I have stumbled a cross different functions that at first seem for example Odd, but they are actully neither because of its Domain.

Example:Fourier Series with

> f(t) = 2*pi*t , t in [0,2*pi).

This function is neither odd nor even because of the given domain and i can not understand why ?

Does the non-existence of negative numbers in the domain mean that the function is  neither odd nor even? Since there can't be any symmetry ?

Can we plot negative numbers even if no negative numbers in the domain exist ?

[This is how the Tutor drew the function to explain why is it neither odd nor even](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DH1N.png)
and i am confused how are we even allowed to plot negative numbers, because of the domain...

Thank you in advance

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is just a guess, but in view of the word "periodisch" (??) on the diagram and the reference to Fourier series the tutor intended that the domain of the function is extended to all real numbers by the requirement that the function is periodic of period $2 \pi$.

Comment: "This function is neither odd nor even because of the given domain and i can not understand why ?"  Because $f(-x)$ is not defined for any $x$ (other than $0$) in the domain and does not exist.  It can not be true that $f(-x) =-f(x)$ nor can it be true that $f(-x) = f(x)$ because $f(-x)$ doesn't equal anything at all.

Comment: Actually looking at the picture I take back what I say.  That function the domain is not $[0,2\pi)$ but the domain is actually all of $\mathbb R$.  Then function is:  Let $x = 2\pi k + t$ where $k$ is an integer and $t \in [0,2\pi)$ then $f(x) = t$.  (And it looks like your tutor messed up).  That function is neither even nor odd because it isn't.  $f(-x) \ne f(x)$ and $f(-x)\ne -f(x)$.